# Android alarmManager, BroadcastReceiver onReceive never called

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set up a alarm to start a job on a certain time but my alarm is never trigger and I don't understand what i'm missing. I'm using android api 22.

Thank you.

```
public class MainActivity extends ProtectedActivity {
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (terminalSettings.GetSettlementEnabled())
        {
            startAlarmManager();
        }
    }

private void startAlarmManager()
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, 
i, 0);

        AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, pi); // 
 Millisec * Second * Minute

    }

}
```

class AlarmBroadcastReceiver

```
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    public AlarmBroadcastReceiver() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

    }
}
```

In the manifest I added those line

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmBroadcastReceiver"></receiver>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `registerReceiver`

```
public static final String Broadcast_PLAY_NEW_AUDIO = "Some key so you know which broadcast is which";

//Create Receiver
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       //Do stuff
    }
};

//Register receiver
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(HomeActivity.Broadcast_PLAY_NEW_AUDIO);
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

//Send Broadcast
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(Broadcast_PLAY_NEW_AUDIO);
sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

Comment: And I put this in mainActivity?